# Regex to extract GPS coordinates C#

Tags: c#, regex

I have a HTML file having GPS coordinates which I want to extract, I am trying to do this by creating a regEx but so far had no luck.

I am using C# to parse the HTML file

Here's the sample GPS Data that should be extracted.

```
S 33 58.254 E 023 53.269
```

any help would be appreciated.

This is the Sample Text in which GPS coordinates are specified

```
<span style="text-decoration: underline;">TOURIST INFORMATION</span><br>
Tourism Office <span style="font-style: italic;">(S 33 58.254 E 023
53.269, Gammasi St, 042-281-1098,)
```

and I need to only extract out `S 33 58.254 E 023 53.269`

Comment: Why are you using RegEx instead of the much simpler `string.Split`?

Comment: @Oded I don't think `string.Split` is a good option here. He wants to *extract* GPS codes, not to parse the GPS code itself.

Comment: @Oscar - his edit clarified that. It was unclear before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example in C#, just in case you want to parse the GPS, and not only extract it from the HTML code:

```
var text = @"Some example that contains S 33 58.254 E 023 53.269 
                  and also S 22 58.123 W 021 53.2";
var pattern = @"([SN])\s(\d+)\s(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\s([EW])\s(\d+)\s(\d+(?:\.\d*)?)";
var m = Regex.Matches(text, pattern);
for (int i = 0; i < m.Count; i++) {
    Console.WriteLine("GPS Found: {0}", m[i].Value);
    Console.WriteLine("-----");
    Console.WriteLine(m[i].Groups[1].Value);
    Console.WriteLine(m[i].Groups[2].Value);
    Console.WriteLine(m[i].Groups[3].Value);
    Console.WriteLine(m[i].Groups[4].Value);
    Console.WriteLine(m[i].Groups[5].Value);
    Console.WriteLine(m[i].Groups[6].Value);
    Console.WriteLine("-----");
}
```

The above example will print:

```
GPS Found: S 33 58.254 E 023 53.269  
-----  
S  
33  
58.254  
E  
023  
53.269  
-----  
GPS Found: S 22 58.123 W 021 53.2  
-----  
S  
22  
58.123  
W  
021  
53.2  
-----
```

**Edit:**
I don't really know if values like `53.2` could be integers, like `53`, but I had that in count just in case.

Answer (score 1):

This is a basic match, just play with it a bit for better results:

```
[SN]\s\d+\s\d+\.\d+\s[EW]\s\d+\s\d+\.\d+
```

Comment: It's `\s` (lowercase 's') for whitespace, not `\S`.

Answer (score 0):

I would first start by examining the "possibilities". I would write

`[SN]\s-?\d{1,3]\s\d+\.\d+\s[EW]\s-?\d{1,3]\s\d+\.\d+`

This is just a spitball goodluck!

Answer (score 0):

If your data pattern is constant, I mean the span style part (`< span style="font-style: italic;" >`)

Why dont you simply try out `GetStringBetween` `italic;">(` and `,`

Below is the method I wrote for my use:

```
public static string GetStringBetween(string input, int searchStartIndex, string startMarker, string endMarker, out int foundAtIndex)
{
    foundAtIndex = -1;
    if (input == null)
        return null;
    int st = searchStartIndex;

    int startIndex = input.IndexOf(startMarker, st);
    if (startIndex < 0)
        return null;
    int endIndex = input.IndexOf(endMarker, startIndex + startMarker.Length);
    if (endIndex < 0)
        return null;
    int occurenceIndex = startIndex + startMarker.Length;
    string data = input.Substring(occurenceIndex, endIndex - occurenceIndex);
    foundAtIndex = occurenceIndex;
    return data;
}
```

Start with `searchStartIndex = 0` , and then keep calling it in loop with new `searchStartIndex = foundAtIndex` from previous call. This way you will get out all the GPS strings only of interest fromt he full file.